# "EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND" error message

Tags: cmake, eigen, cgal

The demo *Polyhedron* in CGA with `Cmake` Configuring incomplete, gives:

> "EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"

[image: error screenshot]

I've been stuck for a while; any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that Eigen's headers have not been automatically found. Therefore you need to explicitly specify their location by defining the cmake variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` to the appropriate location. Of course, this also means that you need to have [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)'s headers installed somewhere.